# Swift: string - calculating first character position at height?

Tags: swift, string, label

I would like to **shorten long strings** with an **ending of "see more..."**.

Everything goes well if the string does not have new lines.

---

> "The cat ate the cake and went outside the house, without any
>   problems. Then the next day something really bad happened. The owner kicked the cat out, and the little animal had no chance to go back."

becomes

> "The cat ate the cake and went outside the house, without any
>   problems. Then the **see more...**"

---

But besides this, **I would like to limit the height as well**. So that the string can be maximum 200pt in height, like this:

> 2 new lines
>
> >
>
> 1 new line
>
> 3 new lines
>
> >
>
> >
>
> 0 new line

should become

> 2 new lines
>
> >
>
> 1 new line
>
> **See more...**

---

How can I determine, after which character should I to put the "See more..." text?

Code:

```
func shorten(maxWidth : CGFloat) -> NSMutableAttributedString {


        let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body)
        // If height is more than 200pt
        if self.height(withConstrainedWidth: maxWidth, font: font) > 200 {
            // Here.. how?
           return finalString
        }

        // If char is more than 400
        if self.count > 400 {
            // BLA BLA CUT TEXT
            return finalString
        }

        let finalString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : font])

        return finalString
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to calculate anything. Just use constrains. and a UIButton to append more text to the UItextview I think keeping things simple in iOS saves you a ton of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend you not put `see more...` as plain string inside your text.

Better approach is to `UIButton` with `see more...` text right after you label.

In such case you can easily manipulate it's position, form, UI, etc